# Sql Server Update Rows where like '%#186;%'

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-update, updates

Hello I have in my database a bunch of table rows that contain the following values:

```
Street Number 1095 - 4&#186; Esq&#186;
```

and I am trying to remove

```
&#186;
```

from all the rows that contain **&#186**  so that my rows would look like so

```
 Street Number 1095 - 4 Esq
```

The Ideia is only to remove **&#186** from all my rows.
I started to create a query like so

```
UPDATE [dbo].[PersonTable]
   SET [street] =  // The problem I am having is what to put here

 WHERE street like '%&#186;%'
```

Could any one please help me with this issue. Thank´s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186862.aspx)

```
set [street] = replace([street], '&#186;', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the REPLACE function

```
 UPDATE [dbo].[PersonTable]
 SET [street] =  REPLACE([street], '%&#186;%', '')
 WHERE street like '%&#186;%'
```